# Why Atom is slow compared with its contemporaneous CPUs even with out-of-order execution?

Tags: performance, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture

Why is Intel Atom slow even with out-of-order execution since Bay Trail? It has been improving, and now the performance is relatively sufficient for daily uses compared with the old in-order execution models.

However, its speed is still much slower than its contemporaneous models with the same clock speed, especially in terms of single core performance(like the Pentium and Celeron processors with SNB/IVB/Haswell... cores, let alone the Core iX).

What other reasons on the architecture caused the low performance? Considering the OOO has already been implemented.

Comment: The Atom family is tailored for power saving. Whenever something was too much power demanding the designers cut it out. Everything is shallower, less in number and more shared than in the mainstream Intel architecture. These are the reasons you were looking for. Agner Fog microarchitecture PDF describes the differences in detail.

Comment: There are maybe hundreds of small micro-architectural features that distinguish between recent Atom and Core CPUs, and make their power-performance curve different. OOO has been around for multiple generations in the Core family, and yet they still crank up some performance on every new product since.